# How to make put request in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am writing a script that pulls JSON data from xyz.site and puts into site.xyz
Here I am able to pull data from xyz.site through jQuery's `$.getJSON` but I am facing a issue while making a put/post request.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use jQuery ajax method and specify type option as `PUT` or `POST`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url', // your api url
    // jQuery < 1.9.0 -> use type
    // jQuery >= 1.9.0 -> use method
    method: 'PUT', // method is any HTTP method
    data: {}, // data as js object
    success: function() {}
});
```